# Is there any hook available to fetch woo commerce registration form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to implement woocommerce registration form in a separate page.Can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

Use the my account shortcode. If they aren't logged in it will ask them to login or register. 
`[woocommerce_my_account]` is the shortcode. Paste that into your page (if using it from the front end).